# How can I tell from a JUnit test whether an Eclipse project is open?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I need to run Maven from the command line while Eclipse is open. Since this can confuse Eclipse, I configured the two to use different output folders (Maven writes to `target`, Eclipse m2e uses `target-eclipse`). This works very well.

But in one of my unit tests, I need to load classes which are part of a project but not on the classpath. Basically, I build my own URL classloader. Now, I have a problem: Which class folder to add?

If the project is open, `target-eclipse/classes` is the correct choice, otherwise I should use `target/classes`.

Assume that I know the Eclipse folder and the workspace folder. How can I tell from Java code running in a child process of Eclipse (not an Eclipse plugin) which projects are open and which aren't?

The existence of the folder is not a good criteria since the folder isn't deleted when I close a project.

**[EDIT]** Basically my question is: Eclipse must store that information somewhere in `$workspace/.metadata` or in `$ECLIPSE_HOME/configuration`. In which file do I need to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file `[Workspace_Home]/.metadata/.lock` tells You the workspace is open.

The list and settings of projects in the workspace are in `[Workspace_Home]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects`.

<del>It seems like open Java projects have a folder `[Workspace_Home]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/[Project_name]/.indexes`, and closed don't have it.</del> - I double checked it, and it seems I was wrong here.

But I just checked that closed Java projects have a file: `[Workspace_Home]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/[Project_name]/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat`, and open projects don't have it.

Answer (score -1):

I would just use some configuration parameter (a system property for example), telling where the folder is. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html for how to pass system properties when running tests with Maven. The first example in this page shows how to pass the build directory as a system property.

Comment: As I said: I know the folder. How can I check whether the project is open?

Comment: OK. It seems I have misunderstood the question. Maybe it's just because making some unit test do something different if some project is open in Eclipse seems like a complete absurdity to me. Could you elaborate why you need this? A folder is a folder, and whether a project is open in Eclipse or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: My JUnit test starts a Jetty server and I need to restart the instance if a resource in a different project changes. I can't add the project because then Eclipse will complain all the time that changes to the class structure prevent the deployment. I could use JRebel but my solution almost works :-)